# cloudant couchdb multipart insert throwing function_clause error

Tags: node.js, couchdb, cloudant, couchdb-nano

I am trying to insert a media document to cloudant couchdb using below below code.

```
var uuid = require('uuid').v4;

fs.readFile('./test.jpeg', function(err, data) {
    if (!err) {
        var newAttachmentObj = { 
            type: 'media',
            media_mime: 'image/jpeg',
            media_type: 'Photo',
            media_filename: 'rabbit1'
        }

        var filename = 'rabbit1';
        var media_mime =  'image/jpeg';
        var attachment_id = uuid();
        var media_data = data;
        console.log(data);
        console.log(newAttachmentObj);
        console.log(attachment_id);

        db.multipart.insert(newAttachmentObj,
            [{ name: filename, data: media_data, content_type: media_mime }], attachment_id, function (err, body) {
            console.log(body);
            if (err) {
                console.log('Error: Creating a media doc in cloudant.');
                console.log(err);
                // console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
            } else {
                console.log(body);
            }
        })
    }
});
```

Document is getting created in the cloudant couchdb and also we can view the uploaded attachment, but the callback function returns an error as shown below.

```
{ Error: function_clause
  at Request._callback (/home/boatman/anoop/forwarding-module/node_modules/cloudant-nano/lib/nano.js:248:15)
  at Request.self.callback (/home/boatman/anoop/forwarding-module/node_modules/request/request.js:188:22)
  at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
  at Request.emit (events.js:213:7)
  at Request.<anonymous> (/home/boatman/anoop/forwarding-module/node_modules/request/request.js:1171:10)
  at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
  at Request.emit (events.js:210:7)
  at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/boatman/anoop/forwarding-module/node_modules/request/request.js:1091:12)
  at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:314:30)
  at emitNone (events.js:110:20)
  at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:207:7)
  at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1045:12)
  at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
  at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:218:9)
    name: 'Error',
    error: 'unknown_error',
    reason: 'function_clause',
    ref: 944644368,
    scope: 'couch',
    statusCode: 500,
    request: 
    { method: 'PUT',
    headers: { 'content-type': 'multipart/related' },
    uri: 'https://XXXXXX:XXXXXX@account_id-bluemix.cloudant.com/db_media/a73d3788-d661-4944-964b-bcffce0286bd',
    multipart: [ [Object], [Object] ] },
    headers: 
    { 'cache-control': 'must-revalidate',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    date: 'Tue, 17 Apr 2018 08:37:28 GMT',
    'x-couch-request-id': '5097b3e876',
    'x-couch-stack-hash': '944644368',
    'x-frame-options': 'DENY',
    'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=31536000',
    'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
    'x-cloudant-request-class': 'write',
    'x-cloudant-backend': 'bm-cc-uk-04',
    via: '1.1 lb1.bm-cc-uk-04 (Glum/1.50.4)',
    statusCode: 500,
    uri: 'https://XXXXXX:XXXXXX@account_id-bluemix.cloudant.com/db_media/a73d3788-d661-4944-964b-bcffce0286bd' },
    errid: 'non_200',
    description: 'couch returned 500' }
```

Please find the image below.
[image: Image trying to attaach]

Comment: `... Document is getting created in the Cloudant ...` Does the created document have all the fields and attachments?

Comment: yes, it has all the  fields and single attachment I was passing.

Comment: Where is the error thrown? In the `NodeJS` code?

Comment: yes, in the callback function that is passed inside multipart.insert()

Comment: Can you post the stack trace when the error occurs?

Comment: have added the stack trace, please check

Comment: Do you run NodeJS code only one time or are you running it multiple times?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169153/discussion-between-anoopgoudar-and-user3405291).

Comment: Why do you include a blank image?

Comment: Its not blank image, thats the image I was trying to upload. Please verify again

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce your conditions with CouchDB 2.1.1, **not** Cloudant, therefore it may not be an exact reproduction, but I thought I'd share my results.

---

I created the following `server.js` file based on your code with a little modification. I used package `nano` for CouchDB **not** `cloudant-nano` since I'm not using Cloudant:

```
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0"; // Ignore rejection, becasue CouchDB SSL certificate is self-signed
var uuid = require('uuid').v4;
const fs = require('fs')
const nano = require('nano')('https://admin:****@192.168.1.106:6984');
// Database 'reproduce' is already created in CouchDB 2.1.1
const db = nano.db.use('reproduce');

fs.readFile('./test.jpeg', function(err, data) {
    if(err){
        console.log('err -> ', err)
    }else if (!err) {
        var newAttachmentObj = {
            type: 'media',
            media_mime: 'image/jpeg',
            media_type: 'Photo',
            media_filename: 'rabbit1'
        }

        var filename = 'rabbit1';
        var media_mime =  'image/jpeg';
        var attachment_id = uuid();
        var media_data = data;
        console.log(data);
        console.log(newAttachmentObj);
        console.log(attachment_id);

        db.multipart.insert(newAttachmentObj,
            [{ name: filename, data: media_data, content_type: media_mime }], attachment_id, function (err, body) {
                console.log(body);
                if (err) {
                    console.log('Error: Creating a media doc in cloudant.');
                    console.log(err);
                    // console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
                } else {
                    console.log(body);
                }
            })
    }
});
```

I placed a sample `test.jpeg` in the same directory as my `server.js` file. Then I ran the code with command `$ node server.js` and I got the following results:

```
$ node server.js 
<Buffer ff d8 ff e1 00 32 45 78 69 66 00 00 49 49 2a 00 08 00 00 00 01 00 98 82 02 00 0e 00 00 00 1a 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 52 61 77 70 69 78 65 6c 20 4c 74 64 ... >
{ type: 'media',
  media_mime: 'image/jpeg',
  media_type: 'Photo',
  media_filename: 'rabbit1' }
ec6a36d1-952e-4d86-9865-3587c6079fb5
{ ok: true,
  id: 'ec6a36d1-952e-4d86-9865-3587c6079fb5',
  rev: '1-896eca9e9980509aeaa8539b281c3257' }
{ ok: true,
  id: 'ec6a36d1-952e-4d86-9865-3587c6079fb5',
  rev: '1-896eca9e9980509aeaa8539b281c3257' }
```

Obviously, I **don't** receive the errors your getting.

Comment: I tried with different image, it worked fine. But its not working with the image downloaded from whatsapp.

Comment: Can you please try with the attached image once

Comment: @AnoopGoudar I also tried with your image, it works fine too.